# How to use Comparable correctly with Dart 3?

Tags: flutter, dart

With Dart SDK 2.x.x. it was okay to use any class as mixin. But with Dart 3 this is no longer allowed as stated in the documentation: https://dart.dev/resources/dart-3-migration#mixin

Now I struggle with the migration. For example, I used the `Comparable` interface as mixin like this:

```dart
mixin Compare<T> on Comparable<T> {
  bool operator <=(T other) => compareTo(other) <= 0;
  bool operator >=(T other) => compareTo(other) >= 0;
  bool operator <(T other) => compareTo(other) < 0;
  bool operator >(T other) => compareTo(other) > 0;
}


class Foo with Comparable<Foo>, Compare<Foo> {
  final int value;

  const Foo({required this.value});
  
  @override
  int compareTo(Foo other) => value.compareTo(other.value);
}
```

But this gives me the error `error: The class 'Comparable' can't be used as a mixin because it's neither a mixin class nor a mixin.`

But if I try to use it as interface like this

```dart
mixin Compare<T> on Comparable<T> {
  bool operator <=(T other) => compareTo(other) <= 0;
  bool operator >=(T other) => compareTo(other) >= 0;
  bool operator <(T other) => compareTo(other) < 0;
  bool operator >(T other) => compareTo(other) > 0;
}


class Foo extends Comparable<Foo> with Compare<Foo> {
  final int value;

  const Foo({required this.value});

  @override
  int compareTo(Foo other) => value.compareTo(other.value);
}
```

I get another error `The class 'Comparable' can't be extended outside of its library because it's an interface class.`

So what is the best way to migrate my code to Dart 3?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's the right way to fix it, but you can do `mixin Compare<T> implements Comparable<T>` and then `class Foo with Compare<Foo>`.  Alternatively the `mixin` can be replaced with extensions (which is [what `package:basics` does](https://pub.dev/documentation/basics/latest/comparable_basics/ComparableBasics.html)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The comment of @jamesdlin answers my question:

```dart
mixin Compare<T> implements Comparable<T> {
  bool operator <=(T other) => compareTo(other) <= 0;
  bool operator >=(T other) => compareTo(other) >= 0;
  bool operator <(T other) => compareTo(other) < 0;
  bool operator >(T other) => compareTo(other) > 0;
}


class Foo with Compare<Foo> {
  final int value;

  const Foo({required this.value});
  
  @override
  int compareTo(Foo other) => value.compareTo(other.value);
}
```

That way, `Compare` can be a mixin.

Answer (score 1):

What you were trying to get can be achieved by extensions.

```dart
void main() {
  final a = Foo(value: 20);
  final b = Foo(value: 40);

  print(a > b);
}

extension Compare<T> on Comparable<T> {
  bool operator <=(T other) => compareTo(other) <= 0;
  bool operator >=(T other) => compareTo(other) >= 0;
  bool operator <(T other) => compareTo(other) < 0;
  bool operator >(T other) => compareTo(other) > 0;
}

class Foo implements Comparable<Foo> {
  final int value;

  const Foo({required this.value});

  @override
  int compareTo(Foo other) => value.compareTo(other.value);
}
```

If you comment extension code, you will get compile time error for `print(a >b);` hence this is valid code as per Dart3